# How would you make a QR code to be circular?

Tags: qr-code

How does qrcodechimp.com create the design around QR codes to make them circular?
**https://share.vidyard.com/watch/sTGmPh8bjsRZkYB12pSdCs?**

thank you

I haven't tried anything except for using their default QR code generator. I would like to use mine instead and realise it's just design.
thanks

Comment: You can even use some pixels inside the QR-square, for instance to display a logo. by embedding the QR square inside a circle, you can add random pixels to fill up the square. More a programming issue in my eyes, but you could place the QR-square over a pixelized circle image,